# Longest Jewish year

Tags: calendar, statistics

This year, 5779, is the longest possible year on the Jewish calendar.  Not only is it a leap year, but Cheshvan and Kislev both have 30 days, for a total of 385 days.  How often does that happen?

Answer (score 3):

It happens in 1371/8512 years, which is about 16.1%.

Comment: Could you add something about how you arrived at (or sourced) that number?

Comment: Where do you get 1371/8512 from? My reading of the Tur’s chart gives 40/247, which is slightly off but still rounds to 16.1%. Where does the difference come from? (And what does 8512 represent? I know of 19 year cycles, 247 year cycles, and over 600K year cycles, but 8512 is new to me.)

Comment: @doni the difference is from https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/64074/759 and see edits

Comment: https://individual.utoronto.ca/kalendis/hebrew/Hebrew-Possible-Weekdays-view.htm